# ArcGIS, Edit Layer Extents with Python script

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-desktop

I would like to **read** and **edit** the Extent Values of each Layer in a MXD-file.

My code:

```
import arcpy

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"D:\Work\myInFile.mxd")

for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):

    if lyr.isFeatureLayer:

         # read
         print lyr.getExtent

         # write
         lyr.getExtent = ({XMin}, {YMin}, {XMax}, {YMax})


mxd.saveACopy(r"D:\Work\myOutFile.mxd")
del mxd
```

The getExtent method is described [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/de/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s300000008000000) But I'm not sure whether this is in any way the correct method.

Answer (score 2):

from your code there is no problem listing layers and getting the extent of layers but i dont think writing method is correct. try the following code with [Extent](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Extent/000v0000006r000000/) method:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.extent = arcpy.Extent(XMin,YMin,XMax,YMax)
```

i hope it helps you...

Answer (score 0):

@KorporalNobbs getExtent is read only.

Il you want zoom on all featureclass you can run

```
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Bloc1")[0]  # or ingore name and get the first df
df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()
```

Extract from [latest Desktop Help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/fr/desktop/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/dataframe-class.htm#M2_GUID-48F7EC9F-155E-4816-BA5D-F7A46E9890FC)

> This performs the same ArcMap operation as Selection > Zoom To
>   Selected Features. One difference is that if no features are selected,
>   it will zoom to the full extent of all layers. If you want to zoom to
>   the extent of selected features for a specific layer, try using the
>   Layer.getSelectedExtent method.

In addition the result get extent with labelling